# Repeat last command matching "two words" zsh

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I want to repeat the last command that matches `foo bar`. Using `!!` doesn't work (it's not the last command I used), and neither does `!foo`, because my history looks something like

```
foo bar dee zep
foo boo lee kee
foo bee
```

If I try to type `!foo bar`, `zsh` auto-completes to `foo bee` (which is the same as `!!` anyway) as I hit the space. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!?foo bar
```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Event-Designators

**Edit**: No, you must not escape the spaces. If you need to add something that is not part of the history expansion, separate it with another `?`, e.g.:

```
echo hello
echo foo
!?echo hello? world # runs "echo hello world"
```

Comment: do you need to escape the spaces?

Comment: Perhaps I'm unable to do this because I'm using `oh-my-zsh`; I can't type `!?foo bar`, because *as I hit the `' '` space key*, zsh autocompletes to `foo bee`; I lose the event designator from the prompt, and further `?` don't help me replace `bee` with `bar`.

Comment: There's an bindkey in `oh-my-zsh`, under `lib/keybindings.zsh`, called `magic-space` (line 23, approx). It does history expansion on `' '`; disabling this bind allowed me to use the `!?` event designator. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Better answer:

```
!{?foo bar?}
```

I find the braces helpful in delaying history expansion with magic-space, though they are documented as:

***Insulate a history reference from adjacent characters (if necessary).***

on the page:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion

Note: in some cases it may be much faster to use the **n**th previous history item syntax like:

```
!-2
```

for 2nd command back, `!-1` is the same as `!!`