# zsh auto-complete event designator

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

(See my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/391521/repeat-last-command-matching-two-words-zsh) for additional context).

I'm migrating to `zsh` from `bash`, and using `oh-my-zsh`. When my `zsh` history looks something like the following:

```
git status
git add -A
git commit
```

I want to be able to re-run `git add -A`. To do that, I could use `!?git add`, which should:

> *!?str[?]* Refer to the most recent command containing str. The trailing ‘?’ is necessary if this reference is to be followed by a modifier or followed by any text that is not to be considered part of str.

The link for zsh event designators is [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Event-Designators).

Unfortunately, I can't do this - as I'm typing `!?git add`, as I hit the `' '`, it auto-completes the command to the most recent command matching `git` (ie, it auto-completes with `git commit`). I can't use the event designator properly because of this auto-completion as I hit the space.

I assume this is an `oh-my-zsh` feature. I have no idea where to look, though - `grep`ing for 'complet' in the `oh-my-zsh` source doesn't get me anywhere.

My question: how do I turn off this feature? Or, if that's not something that's known, where should I be looking - if I was going to implement this auto-complete when whitespace is entered, where would be a logical place to do so in the `oh-my-zsh` framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh and you'll see the line

```
bindkey ' ' magic-space    # also do history expansion on space
```

comment it out to remove this feature.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other ways to skin this cat:

```
!{?git add?}
```

The open braces will let suppress the magic-space expansion on the first space and then if you use tab after the close brace it will expand on the same line, like magic. Of course `!{?git a?}` would be enough.

```
!?add
```

You don't need the `git` at all, in this case at least. After the second `d` you can either hit return or tab. If there's a lot of history between you and the command, this would find the three characters `add` at any point in the command so that might be a problem.

**zsh history expansion** is detailed in the docs at:

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#History-Expansion